# Font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased not working on mobile Safari

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, fonts, safari

The font I am using is Lato at font-weight: 100. This caused issues in Safari where it looked way too thin. I added this code:

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

...and the problem was fixed on desktop Safari AND on Safari's built in iPhone Safari tester. However, on an actual iPhone there is no effect.

The site is on test.silverlineentertainment.com right now if that helps!

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=font-smooth this feature is still not supported in iOS Safari 11.3.

Comment: oh no!! Would it be acceptable to target just iOS browsers to increase the font-weight on those?

Comment: Optimization is always done for the weakest element. That said, `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` works for me on `iPhone X`.